# How to prevent changing/deleting custom properties by user (MS Office)

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I'm creating an Add-in for MS Word and one of the functions is creating and setting the documents property. Unfortunately, user can go to the document properties in MS Word and change the value or even delete the property.

I was thinking about storing the property with the value and setting it before every document save. But is it possible to catch BeforeSave event in Add-in's code?

Another way I was taking into account is some kind of read-only prop/value, but read-only for user and editable for the Add-in. But again, it's probably impossible...

If it helps I've put code below I'm using to add and set PropName and PropValue.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve it? 
Thanks.

```
        Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties;
        properties = (Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties)
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties;

        properties.Add("PropName", false,
            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString,
            "PropValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that there is a possibility to catch Save events in Add-in. It can be solved by putting: Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.DocumentBeforeSave handler in ThisAddIn_Startup.

So, I'll try to solve my problem by saving the name and value of the property and always, before the document is saved I'll check if the property exists and set it OR create it and set stored values (or delete and create without checking - doesn't matter).

Kind regards,
Konfiuzd

Answer (score 0):

You could also store things in [custom XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-custom-xml-parts-to-documents-by-using-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019), the only way anyone could edit that is by edit the docx file outside of Word. It can't be used in fields though.

Comment: Thanks Chris, it's a good tip and looks promising, I'll look at it closer. I'm <15 rep, so I can't give you +1 :(